# Alternative to Multinomial Logistic Regression when observations are not independent?

Tags: regression, logistic, independence, multinomial-distribution

I am dealing with an experimental design with a categorical IV and DV:
In a linguistic experiment, I asked speakers to form as many sentences as they could using a limited number of words. They were given 12 sets of words, in each set, 1 was an adjective. The adjectives differed in meaning ('semantic class' is my IV, 4 levels). Sometimes speakers used the adjective as an attribute (e.g. He's such a good dog), sometimes as a predicate (e.g. The dog is good), sometimes as a subject, and sometimes as an adverb ('pragmatic function' is my DV, 4 levels). My research question was: Does the choice of pragmatic function (esp. whether an adjective is used as an attribute vs. as a predicate) vary depending on the meaning of the adjective?
Statistical test: Since I have categorical variables only I wanted to use a multinomial logistic regression model. Hoooowever, my data violates the Assumption of Independence, because my participants were allowed to produce several sentences with the same adjective (in other words, I don't only have one data point for each adjective from each participant).

How do I get around the problem of having several data points per item from my participants? Is there such a thing as a mixed effects multinomial logistic regression? If so, is it implemented in R? Thanks so much for your help!